# Limit the number of line in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uitextview

## Question

Is there any way to "accurately" limit the number of line in UITextView for target iOS 5.0?

## What I had tried

As I had search in stack overflow. I had found these question been ask before in links below.
[In UITextView, how to get the point that next input will begin another line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444039/in-uitextview-how-to-get-the-point-that-next-input-will-begin-another-line)
[Limit the number of lines for UITextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225763/limit-the-number-of-lines-for-uitextview)
[Limit number of lines in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850450/limit-number-of-lines-in-uitextview)

But I still can't get the accurate number of line in `UITextView` when I tried to decide whether to return YES or NO in `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`.
I had tried used the code which is the answer of [Limiting text in a UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411398/limiting-text-in-a-uitextview/728716#728716) and the code after modified (remove -15 in the answer) is showing below.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString*)aText
{
        NSString* newText = [aTextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:aRange withString:aText];

        // TODO - find out why the size of the string is smaller than the actual width, so that you get extra, wrapped characters unless you take something off
        CGSize tallerSize = CGSizeMake(aTextView.frame.size.width,aTextView.frame.size.height*2); // pretend there's more vertical space to get that extra line to check on
        CGSize newSize = [newText sizeWithFont:aTextView.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        if (newSize.height > aTextView.frame.size.height)
            {
            [myAppDelegate beep];
            return NO;
            }
        else
            return YES;
}
```

I also figure out a way to get the number of line in `UITextView`. The way is to calculate by `contentSize` property like `textView.contenSize.height/font.lineHeight`. This method can get the accurate number of lines in `UITextView`. But the problem is that `contentSize` get in `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` and `textViewDidChange:` is the old `contentSize`. So I still can't limit the number of lines in UITextView.

## Solution I used

This is kind of workaround but at least it work.

### Step 1

At first you need to create a temporary new UITextView with all the same as the original UITextView but setting the temporary UITextView hidden in .xib file. In this sample code I name the temporary UITextView as `tempTextInputView`

### Step 2

Add new referencing outlet to .h file like
`@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *tempTextInputView;// Use to calculate the number of lines in UITextView with new text`

### Step 3

Add code below.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    NSString *newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    _tempTextInputView.text = newText;

    // Calcualte the number of lines with new text in temporary UITextView
    CGRect endRectWithNewText = [_tempTextInputView caretRectForPosition:_tempTextInputView.endOfDocument];
    CGRect beginRectWithNewText = [_tempTextInputView caretRectForPosition:_tempTextInputView.beginningOfDocument];
    float beginOriginY = beginRectWithNewText.origin.y;
    float endOriginY = endRectWithNewText.origin.y;
    int numberOfLines = (endOriginY - beginOriginY)/textView.font.lineHeight + 1;

    if (numberOfLines > maxLinesInTextView) {// Too many lines
        return NO;
    }else{// Number of lines  will not over the limit
        return YES;
    }
}
```

### Discussion

1. `maxLinesInTextView` is an `int` variable represent the maximum number of lines you want.
2. I use a temporary UITextView to setting new text is because when I setting the new text simply in the original UITextView, I got some problem when I typing in ChuYin(注音) keyboard which is a Traditional Chinese input method.
3. I still using `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` but not `textViewDidChange:` is because I got some problem when cache the text before modify with a global NSString and replace the UITextView.text with that global NSString in `textViewDidChange:`.

Comment: It still have a problem when the cursor is in the middle of a string then press return to break line. This solution will get a wrong number of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008713/detect-moment-when-newline-starts-in-uitextview/20009368#20009368), I advise **against** using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` since it is invoked *before* the text is actually changed.

Using the `textViewDidChangeMethod:` makes more sense, since it is invoked *after* the text actually changes. From there you can easily decide what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can use the `UITextViewDelegate` `shouldChangeTextInRange:` method to limit the text entry to the height of the text view:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    // Combine the new text with the old
    let combinedText = (textView.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)

    // Create attributed version of the text
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: combinedText)
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: textView.font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))

    // Get the padding of the text container
    let padding = textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding

    // Create a bounding rect size by subtracting the padding
    // from both sides and allowing for unlimited length 
    let boundingSize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width - padding * 2, CGFloat.max)

    // Get the bounding rect of the attributed text in the
    // given frame
    let boundingRect = attributedText.boundingRectWithSize(boundingSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

    // Compare the boundingRect plus the top and bottom padding
    // to the text view height; if the new bounding height would be
    // less than or equal to the text view height, append the text
    if (boundingRect.size.height + padding * 2 <= textView.frame.size.height){
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One options is to modify the textView yourself in the `shouldChangeTextInRange` delegate method and always return NO (because you already did the work for it).

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString*)aText
{
    NSString* oldText = aTextView.text;
    NSString* newText = [aTextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:aRange withString:aText];
    aTextView.text = newText;

    if(/*aTextView contentSize check herer for number of lines*/)
    {
        //If it's now too big
        aTextView.text = oldText;
    }
    return NO
}
```

Comment: I had tried this but unfortunately it won't work. The contentSize.height of UITextView wasn't change after `aTextView.text = newText`. I add one line `float oldContentSizeHeight = textView.contentSize.height;` before `aTextView.text = newText`. After the `aTextView.text = newText`, contentSize.height get the same value with oldContentSizeHeight even the newText show in `UITextView` had line break. I guess the contentSize will been adjust after `textViewDidChange:`. But still appreciate for your help :)